# How to correctly draw Rectangle using a variable name

Tags: java, draw, paint, rectangles

I am creating a simple java project and want to know how I can create a `Rectangle` using a variable name like so:

```
Rectangle header = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 100);
Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0, 100, 500, 400);
```

I currently have this code for it to be filled with:

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(darkGreen);
    g.fillRect(header.x, header.y, header.width, header.height);
    g.setColor(tan);
    g.fillRect(background.x, background.y, background.width, background.height);
}
```

However nothing appears when I run the code, there is no other errors that I know of, but just in case here is the rest:

```
package trivia;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JPanel{

static Color tan = Color.decode("#F4EBC3");
static Color darkGreen = Color.decode("#E9E0D6");
Rectangle header = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 100);
Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0, 100, 500, 400);

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(darkGreen);
    g.fillRect(header.x, header.y, header.width, header.height);
    g.setColor(tan);
    g.fillRect(background.x, background.y, background.width, background.height);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int HEIGHT = 500;
    int WIDTH = 500;
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
    mainFrame.setSize(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Err, your code never creates any instance of Main, and the draw() method is never called anywhere, so that's not really surprising. Note that you must override paintComponent(), and that's where the painting code should be.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes I think I figured it out actually, I am using `JPanel` instead of `JFrame` and I seemed to make it work after changing a few things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first add a new instance of `Main` (the class) to the `JFrame`. In `paint(Graphics g)` you need to call `draw(g)`.  I personally use advanced double buffering so it doesn't blink all the time -> https://github.com/czipperz/CLibrary/blob/master/src/io/czipperz/github/cLibrary/game/CGameFrame.groovy#L123  (this is Groovy code but it is basically Java).

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you have create class Main that extends JPanel in the main class file (this is not a good practice) and also this class is not instantiated in the static main class.
the main class make this:

```
package trivia;


import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Trivia {


public static void main(String[] args) {
int HEIGHT = 500;
int WIDTH = 500;
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
mainFrame.setSize(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
mainFrame.setVisible(true);
mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
mainFrame.add(myPanel);   
mainFrame.validate();   // Don't forget to validate frame or repaint.


}
```

}

It's more simple that you have two file separated. Try to add the class in a new file so create for example MyPanel.java:

```
package trivia;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

static Color tan = Color.decode("#F4EBC3");
static Color darkGreen = Color.decode("#389900");
Rectangle header = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 100);
Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0, 100, 500, 400);


@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);       
        draw(g);

    } 
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(darkGreen);
    g.fillRect(header.x, header.y, header.width, header.height);
    g.setColor(tan);
    g.fillRect(background.x, background.y, background.width, background.height);
}
```